# File size limit in pimcore CSV import

Tags: csv, pimcore

We are trying to import as CSV file having some objects in PIMCORE. The file is having around 8000 records and size is around 8mb.
The problem is the file is not getting imported and giving some error. But when we are importing csv with file size less then 2mb, it is getting imported successfully.

Just wonderingly, is there any file size hard limit for .csv files import in Pimcore. If yes, then can we override it to accept larger file size?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "some error" is not a good problem description. Can you quote the error?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to change some configuration in php.ini file after opening this file 
change the line 
upload_max_filesize=2M to upload_max_filesize=10M 
then u can upload your file as php default is 2mb for uploading